# How do I make changes to my interface while a button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift3

I've got a button that will do some math when tapped.
Depending on the equation that the user enters, the button will be tapped, but then stay down, as the app takes a while to do the math in the button's function. It would be great if I could have a progress bar show the user during that time. I added one, but the problem is that it doesn't show up when the button has been tapped, as the button is lagging.. it seems that no changes can occur on the screen while the button is tapped down and lagging.

Sorry... I'm a bit of a noob... but I'm stuck...

Comment: Hint: you need to perform the long running computation on a background thread so you can update the user interface while it runs.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry? I don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the math in a background thread, and all the UI related code in the main thread. For exemple, in Swift 3:

```
// Main thread by default: 
// show progress bar here.

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    // Background thread:
    // start your heavy process here, for example: 
    for index in 1...1000 {
        // do something in the loop

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Main thread:
            // update your progress bar here
        }
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Main thread, called after the previous code:
        // hide your progress bar here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'm missing something. My "Heavy process is a statement that loops for a while. what I was trying to do was to increment the progress of my progress bar every time one of these loops was completed.

Comment: Please see my edit. You can update the progress bar at the end of each loop by doing it in the main thread.

Comment: Thanks!! Why do I need the last "DispatchQueue.main.async {", can't I just put that code outside of the parenthesis altogether?

Comment: No, that wouldn't work because `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async` creates a new thread. The code in its block is running in a background thread. Any code after that block would run right away, not at the end of the process.

Answer (score 0):

There is [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch). Here is a basic usage:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject)
{
   // show progress bar  
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
               //  start you main calculation 

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // hide your progress bar
        }
    }
}
```

dispatch_async function asynchronously runs the block of code on the given queue. In first dispatch_async call we dispatch the code to run on background queue. After we get result we update label on main queue with that result

Comment: Value of type 'DispatchQueue' has no member 'asynchronously'

Comment: @JebNicholson This answer is using Swift 2.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention which swift you need ... can you please add proper tag so i can edit accordingly.

Answer (score -3):

I would add the progress bar on load but set it to invisible and then set it to visible as the first action of the button press method, Then do all of the math in the background.

Comment: No, this won't solve the OPs problem. Doing long-running work on the main thread freezes the UI. See Remy's answer for a solution that will work.