# Activity indicator until load the next view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

In my `firstViewController` there is a `UIButton` (GalleryButton) and in my `secondViewController` there is a `UITableView`. When user taps the GalleryButton it takes 2-3 seconds time to open the `secondViewController` and load the images. I want to show an `UIActivityIndicator` until load the  `secondViewController`. How to do so??

Comment: You might be advised to transition immediately and load the images in the background. That way the user has a more seamless experience.

Comment: It seems that there is a downloading process in the second view controller running on the main thread...

Comment: no downloading process. Images are loading from PhotoLibrary

Comment: So, you might want to check what causes the delay and let it executed in a different queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should load the images in a background thread and display the `UIActivityIndicator` in the main thread. I already replied to a similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41529056/1370336

```
// Main thread by default: 
// show progress bar here.

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    // Background thread:
    // start loading your images here

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Main thread, called after the previous code:
        // hide your progress bar here
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new in swift. Can you please tell me where should I write this code??
By the way I am moving to **secondViewController** via **show segue** in storyboard.

Comment: This code should be in `secondViewController`, where you're loading your images (I'm guessing in the viewDidLoad method).

Answer (score 1):

***Create Activity Indicator Programetically in your Second View Controller***

```
    var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray)
```

**Add Below Code in viewDidLoad() of Second View Contoller**

```
   activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
   activityIndicator.center = view.center
   activityIndicator.startAnimating() //For Start Activity Indicator
```

**When Data is Filled in Table View Completely than Add below code for stoping Activity Indicator**

```
   activityIndicator.stopAnimating() //For Stop Activity Indicator
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "NextVC.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *aiStart;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.aiStart.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    self.aiStart.hidden = YES;
    [self.aiStart stopAnimating];
}

- (IBAction)btnShowNextVCTapped:(id)sender {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        self.aiStart.alpha = 0;
        self.aiStart.hidden = NO;
        [self.aiStart startAnimating];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            self.aiStart.alpha = 1;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            NextVC* nextVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NextVC"];

            [self presentViewController:nextVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        }];
    });


}
```